# Steam AWS Machine - OpenGL not using direct rendering

Tags: opengl, ubuntu-16.04, steam

1. System:

   I have a 15vCPU/GPU (NVIDIA) Ubuntu 64bit 16.04LTS machine in the AWS (Amazon Web Services) cloud where I am hopelessly trying to make steam to work.

   I have vncserver running on the ubuntu and other apps work well.
2. Error - Cannot start steam

   "OpenGL GLX context is not using direct rendering, which may cause performance problems"
3. What I have done

   A lot actually but just couldn't crack it! :\

   I have gone through all the tips on stackflow, ubuntu site and adopted all advices where applicable. Reinstalled steam, reconfigured nvidia drivers, tons of reboot but I just cannot makt it work.

   Here are some basic info for kind folks to help out please.

   This GPU server with software Nvidia-375 driver and CUDA8 installed.

   ```
   lspci | grep NVIDIA
   00:03.0 VGA compatible controller: NVIDIA Corporation GK104GL [GRID K520] (rev a1)
   ```
4. My goal: It would be great to have your support to make me run Steam effortlessly via my VNC client connection to my AWS Ubuntu machine.

Answer (score 1):

The problem at hand is, that to create a hardware accelerated OpenGL context with X you actually have to run an X server utilizing your GPU. `vncserver` does not do that! `vncserver` in fact runs its very own Xvfb based X server, that's using no GPU at all. Hence it also doesn't support hardware accelerated OpenGL.

You have to run an X server using the `nvidia` driver in headless mode (i.e. configure in `xorg.conf` it so that it ignores the monitor missing). Also you should not use VNC at all for gaming. It's slow and consumes far too much bandwidth. Steam has a streaming mode and you definitely should use that.

Comment: OK thanks & noted so vncserver is not the way to go. How do I run an X server in headless mode? Can I then be able to install it remotely? I'm happy to stream it if that works.

Comment: @Tarry: Just install it as you would on a local desktop machine `apt-get install xorg-server`, then install the NVidia drivers. Then you must override display detection, so that the X server is started despite no phyical display being connected. For that create a minimal `xorg.conf` that sets the `ConnectedMonitor` driver option to one of the present outputs. Furthermore you'll have to configure X to a) allow operation without input devices connected (`AllowEmptyInput` option) and for security reasons you should disable input device hotplugging (or better yet uninstall X input modules).

Comment: Thanks @datenwolf - I'll try that and see if it works.